# jquery this refer to class in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, this, parent

I have several divs that contain a date inside of them in a p tag. I want only those divs that display the current date to display.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <p class="date">2013/12/18</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p class="date">2013/12/19</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p class="date">2013/12/20</p>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript that I have right now, and it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();

    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();

    var date = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
        ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
        ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;

    if($('.date').html() == date){
        $(this).parent().css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

The code gets into the if statement, but the .css() line isn't working. Any suggestions on why this isnt working and how to fix it?

Comment: Define "isn't working". Do the correct elements not appear, or are too many visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body of the function `$(document).ready`, the value of `this` is not your `.date` element

Replace

```
if($('.date').html() == date){
    $(this).parent().css('display', 'block');
}
```

with

```
$('.date').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == date) {
        $(this).parent().css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

In this second portion of code, you are in the body of the `.each()` function: `this` represents your element with class `date`

Comment: Why not using `filter` method?

Comment: @undefined Your answer is actually prettier. I used a more simple implementation to explain more easily why the original code doesn't work

Comment: @AurélienGasser: Just wondering. Are you actually a moderator?

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes, the ♦ at the end of my user name means I'm a moderator

Answer (score 1):

`if` doesn't create scope in JavaScript, in your code `this` refers to the `window` object, you have to query the DOM and select the element, but it also doesn't solve the issue here as `html` method only returns html content of the first matched element, the suitable method here is `filter`:

```
$('.date').filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === date;
}).parent().show();
```